# What is the cause of my hanging freezing computer?

Tags: windows-10, freeze, troubleshooting

Tech Support Guy System Info Utility version 1.0.0.4

OS Version: Microsoft Windows 10 Home, 64 bit

Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2310 CPU @ 2.90GHz, Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7

Processor Count: 4

RAM: 8174 Mb (DDR3 2 sticks 4gb each)

Graphics Card: Radeon RX 570 Series, -1 Mb

Hard Drives: C: 465 GB (90 GB Free); D: 465 GB (14 GB Free);

Motherboard: ASUSTeK Computer INC., P8H61-M LE

Antivirus: Windows Defender, Disabled

PSU: Seasonic SI2II Bronze

IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII

Good day,

Until recently, this week, I never had a GPU and only used a generic PSU. But just 3 weeks ago, I bought a GPU and a good quality PSU.

I am totally at a loss here. I have been having problems with my computer for several years now.

**What happened before the upgrade:**

- My computer would instantly hang, and then the screen would shatter (showing lines). 1-2 years ago, this occurrence would be accompanied by a loud, repeating sound when I was playing a game, for instance, but not all the time 90% of the time, the screen would freeze. This can occur even on the simplest of tasks, not necessarily playing games, but more demanding games cause more hangs based on my observation.
- There were a few instances where it instantly rebooted instead of hanging.
- On half of the instances, a Blue screen of death (BSOD) would just appear and show a huge variety of error messages every time.
- Restarting my PC when I hanged will create an overheating error most of the time where my CPU is very hot. I will bypass this all the time by pressing "Disable changes and Exit" in the BIOS in the start-up.

Last year, this happened and stopped appearing for about 6-8 months, then started appearing 1-2 weeks ago on an intermittent basis. Probably since 1-2 weeks ago, it would occur 1-3 times every 1 to 2 days. I never cleaned my computer for about 5-7 years until I decided to get a GPU and PSU wherein I opened my computer and cleaned all the components.

Removed the fan facing the motherboard, cleaned the fan, heatsink, and motherboard of dust. Also removed the thermal paste, then re-applied and re-attached. The rams were very dirty; there were layers of dust in the ram to the point the circuits were covered in dust. I thought this was the problem and cleaned it carefully with dry tissue paper until 95-99% of the dust was clear. I also cleaned the other fan at the back of my CPU.

Basically, the only thing I did not clean is my generic power supply because I was thinking of replacing it anyway.

**After the upgrade:**

- My computer would still hang, but this time my screen would simply freeze the most recent image on my screen, then after about 5-10 seconds, my monitor will completely lose signal and not detect anything from my computer. My keyboard still works when I press caps lock for a few moments after the screen has turned black, then after that, it will also stop taking in any input. I cannot do anything but restart the computer.
  The first instance it hanged after I got the GPU just yesterday is that my optical drive suddenly opened when I restart my computer after the freeze. My optical drive never opens, also pressing the button does not even open it because it is broken. So I was shocked it opened even. I doubt it is the PSU that is the culprit because this is a brand new Seasonic power supply, and I have been having freezing problems before I even upgraded.
  There were no blue screens of deaths ever since the upgrade (which happened almost every 1-2 days for about 2-3 weeks before I bought my GPU and PSU), so the blue screens stopped appearing, only the freeze.
- No more overheating errors ever of CPU when restarting, unlike before the upgrade

**Tests Done:**

- So I did a "Windows Memory Diagnostic," and it ran the "Standard"
  tests once then rebooted and said it had no problems encountered. But
  only for about 15 minutes and did not do any memtest yet.
- I ran Furmark for 45 mins to test GPU stability, Prime95 to test my
  CPU and Ram for 5 hours. I ran MSI afterburner while playing games and learned that even at temperatures below 60C on GPU and CPU,
  my computer can still freeze during games. No errors/crashes were found during stress tests. Freezes occur 95% of the time while playing games, but
  there was one instance it hanged when I was right-clicking a folder
- I'm not sure if my hard drive can be a culprit because I never have corrupted files despite it being extremely slow. Also, most of the time, my computer is slow at right-clicking or loading things or starts to get sluggish because of disk utilization where it gets capped out at 100% in many instances. Sometimes it gets capped with just a
  low usage of memory--oddly.
- Checked motherboards for bloated capacitors. They looked clean and
  uniformly cylindrical.

So I am wondering what my computer's problem is. Also, I am worried that my new GPU and PSU might get damaged from a possible defective motherboard, processor, ram, or hard drive. As most of these are
probably about 6-8 years old or more.

Comment: If you suspect your memory you should test it.  It is not clear what your question is exactly?

Comment: Sorry about that I just copied the title from my post from a forum, I revised the body and title to the updated. I will run memtest tonight. I just thought it some problem should have occurred if it was the ram when I ran Prime95

Comment: Prime95 is only a CPU stress test.

Comment: Oh didn't know that. I just saw some websites saying it tests for ram and CPU as well and the Prime95 settings have some heavy ram or heavy CPU options. I'll run memtest today

Comment: Actually your hard drive *could* be responsible for some of these symptoms, while CPU overheating could explain the rest. Do you have only one drive? Are your games running off of that "extremely slow" drive too?

Comment: @Romen My hard drive is extremely slow. After I upgraded all my components except the hard drive it still took 12 mins to boot with almost no improvement. Changing it to an SSD caused it to boot in 20 seconds lol. I gave up an upgraded the whole thing. But then this hard drive is still plugged in my computer but only as a secondary drive since it has a different OS from my previous installation. Oddly, there are very few times when I turn on my computer and it gets stuck in a black screen and I have to restart my PC. I don't know why it happens for my new PC maybe the hard drive? But no hangs

Comment: Your system freezes because you still have the old hard drive present, the BIOS still attempts to detected it on boot up.  Sometimes the drive is ok enough to be detected sometimes it isn't.  Clearly the old drive needs to be trashed ASAP, copy the data off it.  Run dban to wipe any sensitive data off of it, and trash it or smash it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the issue could be coming from the motherboard. The reason being is you stopped getting BSoDs and screen shatters after popping in a new GPU. However, I would do a thorough check of the harddrive as well, to make sure you don't have any corrupt sectors.

In an elevated command prompt (Start > Run > CMD.EXE AS ADMIN) type in 'CHKDSK /F /R /X', press enter and then type 'shutdown -r -t 0' to immediately reboot and run CHKDSK.

After CHKDSK has ran, look for the log in Event Viewer (R-Click Start Meny > Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application > Filter Current Log > 26226 > Ok) and post the contents here.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is helpful considering replacing all my computer's components soon to a newer model. Will update the information here soon